# Customizing select menu in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using a select element with `data-native-menu="false"`.I want to customize things like the width of the dialog that appears,color,text allignment etc.After inspecting the elements I figured out I can target the menu contents with something like this:

```
#custom-menu>li{
text-align: right !important;
color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

But it is not working.Can anyone help me with this?.Thanks in advance.

You can see a sample here - http://jsfiddle.net/8nVTC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect deeper, the above properties get overridden on the list item's child anchor element, hence you have to use its class to set these:

```
.ui-link-inherit {
    color: #FF0000 !important;
    text-align: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8nVTC/5/